# Delphi - how do I export a rave report to Excel

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I have a rave report that has 50 pages

I need to generate a PDF report with that has pages 1 to 50 and

generate a excel spread sheet that has pages 1 to page 3

I am using Delphi 2006 Rave reports 6.5 and gnostice v2.5

**Question:**

How do I export the first 3 pages of the report to excel?

Comment: Please edit (state more precisely) the question title, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Rave doesn't support excel directly.

Dump your data to a csv which excel can open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ESB RaveViewer (free tool)
http://www.esbconsult.com/raveaddons/esbraveviewer.htm